# How to perform routeGuard in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Im building an app in angularJS where a user can Login to the the admin Panel.

Router config

```
app.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",($routeProvider,$locationProvider)=>{
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
$routeProvider
    .when("/",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/enterticket.html"
    })
    .when("/adminlogin",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/adminlogin.html",
        controller: "adminlogin"
    })
    //panel is the admin section
    .when("/panel",{
        controller: "panel",
        templateUrl: "app/views/panel.html",
    })
```

}])

There's a service that authenticates the user to grant access to the admin panel,
auth service

```
app.service("auth",["$http","$location",function($http){
let api = (window.location.origin)+"/auth";
 this.auth = function () {$http.get(api).then((rez)=>{
    //is session is not set on server
     if(!rez.data.state){
        window.location.href = "#/adminlogin"
 })}
```

}])

And finally theres the admin component

```
app.controller("panel",["$scope","$http","auth",function($scope,$http,auth){
auth.auth();
$scope.addTicket = ()=>{
   let bearer = $scope.bearer;
    let api = (window.location.origin)+"/addticket";
    let postfields = JSON.stringify({"bearer":bearer});
    $http.post(api,postfields).then((rez)=>{
        console.log(rez);
    })
}
```

}])

This setup is working well and there is restriction for the admin panel, however, when someone attempts to visit the admin panel without logging in, the browser flashes the admin panel template and then quickly reverts back to the admin login. Can someone suggest a way of preventing that awkward flash or even tell me a better way of implementing angularJS routeGuards, thank so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to use resolve in when.

I forked another project and you need to tweak the code as per your requirement. (http://plnkr.co/edit/PAYTAr1sOoCmkP8q)

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('app')
.factory("authService", function($q, $timeout){
   return {
       verify: function(){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $timeout(function(){
               
            //  deferred.resolve(true); // if the user is allowed to access admin panel
            deferred.reject(false); // if the user is not logged in
           },1000);
           return deferred.promise;
       }
   };
});


angular.module('app')
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
     $scope.message = "Message in the main controller";
});

angular.module('app')
.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope) {
     
    $scope.hello =  " World";
     
});

angular.module('app')
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    
    $routeProvider.
      when('/option1', {
          
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'templateCtrl',
        resolve: {
            greeting: function(authService, $location){
                
               return authService.verify().then(function(result){ 
                   return true; // if the user is logged in, it will allow the user to access login panel
               }, function(result){
                    $location.path('/login');// if not, it will redirect to login page
                    return false;
               })
               
            }
        }
            
      })
      .when('/login', {
          template: '<div>Login Message</div>'
      })
  });
```

Comment: This isnt working, the panel template never loads either on successful or non succesful login. Plus anybody can open the panel page and get a blank page

Comment: put an alert on result and confirm whether you are executing the correct function. because in earlier version, angularjs used .success and later used .then  ... you need to adjust the code according to your version.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Alaksandar Gene i got your answer to work however it was still flashing the template. I guess the problem was from the resolve not awaiting the http call. So i decided to use cookies instead.

```
app.service("mainauth",function($http,$q,$timeout,$cookies){
this.mainauth = ()=>{
    var defer = $q.defer();
        let api = (window.location.origin)+"/auth";
        if($cookies.get("ticket_admin") == null){
            defer.resolve(false);
        }
        return defer.promise;
}
```

})

Then for the routing:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",($routeProvider,$locationProvider)=>{
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
$routeProvider
    .when("/",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/enterticket.html"
    })
    .when("/adminlogin",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/adminlogin.html",
        controller: "adminlogin"
    })
    .when("/panel",{
        controller: "panel",
        templateUrl: "app/views/panel.html",
        resolve: {
            mainauth: function(mainauth,$location){
                mainauth.mainauth().then((rez)=>{
                    if(!rez){
                        window.location.href = "#/adminlogin"
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

}])

I suppose theres a risk of somebody imitating the cookies, and gaining access so ill put up another service to verify the session incase that happens

```
app.service("auth",["$http","$cookies",function($http,$cookies){
this.forceAuth = function(){
    let url = (window.location.origin)+"/auth";
    $http.get(url).then((rez)=>{
        if(!rez.data.state){
            window.location.href = "#/adminlogin"
        }
    })
}
```

}])

I can then inject the above service in the controller for added security.
PS some might wonder why i didnt inject a service that verifies the cookies directly into the controller, thats because it was still causing a flash